# Can anyone help me find an $x$ for which $\sin x=-1/2$ and $\sin x=\sqrt{2}/2$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I know that $\sin x=0$ when $x$ is of the form $x=n\pi$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

But, I can't figure out an $x$ for which $\sin x=-1/2$ and $\sin x=\sqrt{2}/2$ are both true.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/65755/147263) can help

Comment: One of the random coincidences of $\sin,\cos$ is that we get $\frac \sqrt 12,\frac \sqrt 22, \frac \sqrt 32, \frac\sqrt42$ from certain "easy" fractions of $\pi$.  Do you recall some of these?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596199/solving-a-trigonometric-equation-sin

Comment: If $\sin x=-1/2$ and $\sin x=\sqrt2/2$ then $-1/2=\sqrt2/2$...

Comment: I think you probably made a mistake on this question.  Perhaps you mean that $\sin x = -1/2$ and $\cos x = \sqrt{2}/{2}$?

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution for this equations. If both are satisfied the
solution set is empty.

Comment: whaa(2 to go)aa

Answer (score 1):

You know $\sin(x)$ is periodic. So, if it does not have any solution in $(-\pi,+\pi]$, it would not have solution anywhere else.

$$\sin(x)=-1/2 \Rightarrow x=\pi/6+2k\pi$$
$$\sin(x)=\sqrt{1/2} \Rightarrow x=\pi/4+2k\pi$$

No intersect!